# Phonegap, Android, Jquery Mobile and memory usage

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, memory, cordova, slider

I have 3 different pages and only the first one includes a little bit more logic and variables at the moment. When I am testing slider with my Nexus 7 I got this:

```
07-24 09:36:01.363: D/Cordova(10976):
onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/android_asset/www/testSlider.html)
07-24 09:36:01.363: D/CordovaWebView(10976): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-24 09:36:01.363: D/DroidGap(10976): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
07-24 09:36:01.363: D/DroidGap(10976):
onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/android_asset/www/testSlider.html)
07-24 09:36:17.463: D/dalvikvm(10976): GC_CONCURRENT freed 470K, 10%
free 8084K/8967K, paused 19ms+7ms, total 83ms
```

So is it about memory then or is there huge memory leak in jquery mobile slider?
Can it be even possible, because I've got only 3 almost empty pages and there is the last one where is sliders (not working though), they are working in the browser, but not in nexus 7.

If somebody has implemented multi page app in phonegap + jqm + Android, could you pls tell me is that possible and if it is, how can I increase the amount of memory in jvm in Nexus or emulator or how to management memory usage in my app. I just inserted a couple of console-logs to slider to check is it working or not, but I just got that memory-line, not logs at all and like I said, it is working in browsers, but not in real device.

**And the code is here**

```
package com.mycordova.hellocordova;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class HelloCordovaActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 

<title>conditions</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function onload(){
    $("#temperature").on("change", function(e){
        var newTemp = $("#temperature").val();
        console.log("newTempnewTempnewTempnewTemp---->" +newTemp)
        $("#temp").val(newTemp);
    });


}

</script>

</head> 

<body onload="onload()"> 
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">


<h1>Conditions</h1>
    </div>


    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="temperature">Temperature22:</label>
        <input type="range" name="temperature" id="temperature" value="15" min="-15" max="60" data-highlight="true" />
        <label for="temp">Echo Temp</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="temp" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

​And jumping from page to page is happening like that. Conditions-page is the problematic one!

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar" style="font-size: -2">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-active">Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="conditions.html" data-transition="pop"
        data-direction="reverse">Conditions</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Now the situation is that the slider-page (called conditions) is working fine when it is the first page, but when it is the second page it is not working anymore. I tried to put both of the pages inside the first page, but same final result. But this has been helpful, cause I was blaming JQM and my jS, so now I know that it is something else.

BTW when I test my app in the browser, it is not working, but when I refresh the page, it will start to work. This is the strangest application what I have ever done.

@tencent was askin more log and here it is:

```
07-24 23:26:59.910: D/Cordova(20550): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html#conditions)
07-24 23:26:59.910: D/CordovaWebView(20550): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-24 23:26:59.910: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
07-24 23:26:59.910: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html#conditions)---> Transition to next page where that slider is.
07-24 23:27:21.490: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(20550): Ignore this event**----> I Tried to write to disabled echo-fied**
07-24 23:27:21.690: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(20550): Ignore this event
07-24 23:27:28.120: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(20550): Ignore this event
07-24 23:27:33.470: D/CordovaWebView(20550): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-24 23:27:33.470: D/DroidGap(20550): onDestroy()**--->Somewhere here it crashed and closed the app!!**
07-24 23:27:33.480: D/CordovaWebView(20550): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-24 23:27:33.480: D/CordovaWebView(20550): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-24 23:27:33.670: D/DroidGap(20550): DroidGap.onCreate()
07-24 23:27:33.690: D/CordovaWebView(20550): Origin to allow: http://127.0.0.1*
07-24 23:27:33.690: I/CordovaLog(20550): Found log level DEBUG
07-24 23:27:33.690: I/CordovaLog(20550): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
07-24 23:27:33.690: I/CordovaLog(20550): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
07-24 23:27:33.690: D/CordovaLog(20550): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
07-24 23:27:33.700: D/DroidGap(20550): DroidGap.init()
07-24 23:27:33.700: D/CordovaWebView(20550): >>>loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
07-24 23:27:33.700: D/PluginManager(20550): init()
07-24 23:27:33.700: D/CordovaWebView(20550): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-24 23:27:33.710: D/CordovaLog(20550): exception firing pause event from native
07-24 23:27:33.710: D/CordovaLog(20550): null: Line 1 : exception firing pause event from native
07-24 23:27:33.710: I/Web Console(20550): exception firing pause event from native at null:1
07-24 23:27:33.710: D/CordovaLog(20550): exception firing destroy event from native
07-24 23:27:33.710: D/CordovaLog(20550): null: Line 1 : exception firing destroy event from native
07-24 23:27:33.710: I/Web Console(20550): exception firing destroy event from native at null:1
07-24 23:27:33.710: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(20550): Ignore this event
07-24 23:27:33.730: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(onPageStarted,about:blank)
07-24 23:27:33.730: D/Cordova(20550): onPageFinished(about:blank)
07-24 23:27:33.730: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
07-24 23:27:33.730: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(exit,null)
07-24 23:27:33.760: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
07-24 23:27:33.770: D/CordovaWebView(20550): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-24 23:27:33.810: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(20550): Ignore this event
07-24 23:27:33.820: D/DroidGap(20550): onDestroy()
07-24 23:27:33.820: D/CordovaWebView(20550): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-24 23:27:33.820: D/CordovaWebView(20550): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-24 23:27:34.160: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20550): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-24 23:27:34.250: D/CordovaLog(20550): exception firing pause event from native
07-24 23:27:34.250: D/CordovaLog(20550): null: Line 1 : exception firing pause event from native
07-24 23:27:34.250: I/Web Console(20550): exception firing pause event from native at null:1
07-24 23:27:34.260: D/CordovaLog(20550): exception firing destroy event from native
07-24 23:27:34.260: D/CordovaLog(20550): null: Line 1 : exception firing destroy event from native
07-24 23:27:34.260: I/Web Console(20550): exception firing destroy event from native at null:1
07-24 23:27:34.260: D/Cordova(20550): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
07-24 23:27:34.260: D/CordovaWebView(20550): >>> loadUrlNow()
07-24 23:27:34.260: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
07-24 23:27:34.260: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
07-24 23:27:34.270: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(onPageStarted,about:blank)
07-24 23:27:34.290: D/Cordova(20550): onPageFinished(about:blank)
07-24 23:27:34.290: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
07-24 23:27:34.300: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(exit,null)
07-24 23:27:36.270: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(spinner,stop)
07-24 23:27:36.300: D/DroidGap(20550): onMessage(spinner,stop)
```

Comment: Have you tested this using Chrome standalone on the device? If you could put the test page on the web I could try debugging from my phone if that is a possibility. JS shouldn't be crashing your app though so something else is likely going on.

Comment: How is it possible to test it in Nexus Chrome browser if I haven't got any server? You can check the code from here: http://jsfiddle.net/6rT6P/12/ and it is working fine in browser, but not in device. I hope that you or somebody invent something, cause this is showstopper and I can't continue. I always have used four days to work this out, no success. I have tried about 5 different js/JQM solution for that slider, but no one has worked in Nexus 7 4.1 Jelly Bean. THANKS!

Comment: I don't even see the problem. What are you asking?

Comment: Put the test file on your sd card. You can navigate to it from chrome as such: file:///sdcard/test.html (Note the three slashes not two)

Comment: I am asking that why isn't working in Nexus 7 (phonegap app). Is there a bug, because if I understand right, it eats all of the memory and that's why it is not working. I am testing exactly the same page in Nexus 7 than in Fiddle, except there is console.log lines and I never see them and echo-box gets never any value. If somebody owns Android-phone, it would be nice if somebody could test this. Another q was that is it even possbile that 3 pages eats all of the memory. There is no SD-card in Nexus 7, sorry! I will put the file to dropbox...

Comment: Nexus 7 still has an sdcard directory so that applications can see it as 'external storage'. Its the same on the Galaxy Nexus which also uses this 'fake sdcard' method. As for your Fiddle test, it works on my Galaxy Nexus using chrome. I believe your issue may be in your implementation of the WebView, could you post your code for implementation and additionally post the full stack trace of the crash.

Comment: @tencent It is working fine as a HTML-page in Nexus Chrome, read from Dropbox. No problem at all. What this should tell me? Could you test it as a phonegap app as well? Thanks a lot all of you, I hope that we  can solve the problem annoying me too much. I test it next as a opening page of my phonecap app.

Comment: The stacktrace does not show a crash just a typical dalvik clean garbage collection. Does the app actually crash? If you could post the code instantiating the webview and show how you are switching pages it may shed some light on your problem but currently it is too vague to give an answer.

Comment: @tencent And yes, I changed my testSlider.html to first page and it is working. Before App didn't do anything, it just was. Now I could prove that slider really is working, so there is something else. I will edit my Q with info you asked! What does it mean, how I am instantiating my webview? My first android app u know ;)

Comment: Try preventing Ajax loading of the links by adding this to the href attributes. data-ajax="false"

Comment: I tried, no success :( This is really weird, even if I took everything off from index.html (left only link), the second page (condition is not working and it doesn't matter is it inside the first page or own page.